# I created an OnClick Listener in My Adapter Class How do i pass it along to a fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, onclick

```
public ViewTags(View view) {
        super(view);        
mCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.DeleteCheckBox);
        mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
```

How can I implement my On Click Listener in my fragment Class?

Answer (score 0):

You may override the constructor method and pass the OnClickListener interface.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends AnyAdapter {

private OnClicListener listener;

public MyCustomAdapter (OnClicListener listener){
this.listener = listener;
}

[....] mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(listener);

}
```

Then you may implement the OnClicListener on the class that will use the adapter and pass the class itself as a parameter.